# Load dependencies while compiling in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I am trying out hadoop tutorial for sample [WordCount](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

It asks to compile the program as follows:

```
$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

Executing javac with hadoop command seems to load all the dependencies for hadoop auomatically. Now I am trying out the same from eclipse. How can I imitate this / load hadoop dependencies / execute hadoop.sh while compiling through eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use eclipse's ability to run [external tools](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm)